# How do I change the hex size in a seaborn jointplot? (the hexes themselves, not the bins)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, seaborn

Using a hexagonal jointplot in Seaborn to produce some "heat maps" showing where on the court basketball players take the most shots. The data comes from a pandas dataframe, where LocX represents the player's horizontal position on the court (-250 and 250 are the sidelines, 0 is in line with the basket), and LocY is the length-wise distance from the basket. I use the same code to produce maps for multiple players, but the size of the hexagons varies wildly between players (even when two players have a similar number of total shots). Here is one that comes out just as I'd like [Good Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5U6q.png),

[image]

but here is one that doesn't work at all [Bad Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKVAj.png).

[image]

Here is my code generating it:

```
cmap=plt.cm.gist_heat_r
joint_shot_chart = sns.jointplot(shot_df.LocX, shot_df.LocY, stat_func=None, kind='hex', space=0, color=cmap(.2), cmap=cmap)
```

Is there a kwarg that I can use to change the size of the hexagons?

Comment: try use "gridsize" as a parameter? there is a discussion about it. https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/186

Comment: That worked! Really weird, I tried that earlier with no luck. Wonder what I was doing wrong. Thanks a ton!

Comment: nice, I'm glad that it works.

Comment: Did u add the bg image externally or is there any function in seaborn?

Answer (score 13):

You can parse the `gridsize` argument. A higher value results in smaller hexbins.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
joint_kws=dict(gridsize=5)
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips,kind="hex", joint_kws= joint_kws)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `AttributeError: 'QuadMesh' object has no property 'gridsize'`

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips,kind="hex",gridsize=20)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).